# pyinstaller icon not changing for the executable file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have the app.py in root folder and favicon.ico in images/favicon.ico

When I create an executable file with pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=images/favicon.ico app.py
```

The app executable is just showing the Mac's own icon for an executable file.
I have tried changing the app name and moving the file to another directory as suggested in another question. I am on a Mac OS with latest Monterey, and latest Python.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

.ico files are for Windows.

For MacOs according to the documentation you have to use the `icns` file extension.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-i
*"FILE.icns: apply the icon to the .app bundle on Mac OS"*

Comment: I have tried using a icns format as well (converted a 32x32 PNG to ICNS). The icon is not showing?

Comment: I can't try since I don't have a Mac. But I know the option works well for a windows build... Have you deleted (or edited) the .spec file before rebuild ?

Comment: What can be modified in the .spec file? There is already this in the file `entitlements_file=None , icon='images/favicon.icns'`

Comment: I guess it should be good then... I don't know what else could be wrong..

Answer (score 0):

The documentations says: "When you build a windowed Mac OS X app (that is, running in Mac OS X, you specify the --onefile --windowed options), the spec file contains an additional statement to create the Mac OS X application bundle, or app folder:"

So I added the --windowed option and now the icon shows!